# Extract GET request contents from Scapy packet

Tags: python-2.7, scapy, pcap

We are parsing pcap files that are created via the tcpdump command. Inside these pcap files we are attempting to extract the GET request information in the Raw field and print it in a readable format.

```
pkts = rdpcap(filename)
for pkt in pkts:
    if Raw in pkt:
        raw_test = pkt[Raw].load
        if "GET" in raw_test:
             #do stuff
```

The resulting text of raw_test comes out looking like this:
`▒פ▒▒▒▒▒▒2▒nk▒N▒▒bEr▒▒(|▒▒▒▒Ǫ=▒▒Ih▒H+%▒2.▒L[▒▒▒sl▒E▒▒▒k6▒]=މf▒d▒O▒hB{6s▒▒▒7O2!PCG&▒A.4I▒耓▒X▒▒▒W]▒▒M5@▒▒▒vK▒#Ċ▒    ▒▒▒m]Zb_▒8▒▒▒nb~
]▒h▒6▒.̠▒49ؾG?▒▒▒4▒Ӹ▒▒G▒▒́G▒:Y▒▒▒▒.▒8▒▒d▒i4▒JAC)▒▒AO▒k▒z-▒▒S30▒X?▒▒W5B▒yW▒m▒▒▒/ƈ:G▒▒▒E▒▒<▒▒▒m▒]▒▒▒▒t▒:▒▒▒Ŕ▒W▒▒D▒E▒▒▒▒▒࿄▒▒zZ▒▒x▒]▒▒{{▒▒u▒){▒▒o▒▒G▒F▒▒▒▒▒v
                                                                    ▒▒▒b.`

We have also tried formatting it via `pkt.sprintf(“{Raw:%Raw.load%}\n”)` but that has yielded the same output

P.S. Please do not link us to other related stack posts/questions as we have come across many of them already, and none of them seem to fix our problem.

Thank you in advance, any help is greatly appreciated!.

Comment: *"as we have come across many of them already, and none of them seem to fix our problem"* - This  says nothing about what you've actually tried but only that you've tried something unspecified and failed in an also unspecific way. In other words, this information is practically useless.

Comment: Your code (with some `print raw_test` added) works perfectly for me. I have no idea what you are doing differently. Maybe you have some input data which contain 'GET' somewhere but are not HTTP? It might be helpful to provide the input your are trying to process.

Comment: That's what we are confused about unfortunately before we would be able to print raw_test and the packet information would be completely readable along with the get request information. We have tried tracing our changes and don't see what could have changed this. We have also tried <code>pkt.getlayer(TCP) </code> which yields the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this, I assume that http is targeted to port 80

```
if TCP in pkt and pkt[TCP].dport == 80 \
            and pkt[TCP].load.startswith("GET") :
        print pkt[TCP].load
```

Comment: We tried the code you suggested and we were getting an attribute error for load inside the TCP layer. We used pkt.show to examine the entire contents and there was no load nested inside TCP, only Raw. Not sure why this is.

Comment: Have you analysed the packet capture with tools like wireshark ?